# How to get unreaded sms/missed calls from my Android device?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing Android application and I need to get unreaded sms/missed calls from my Android device. Are there any ways that I can do it? I hope there are some content provider that can do it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you got any answer for your question? I am looking for incoming call unread count can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

To get the sms uread count.i think this will work for you

```
  public static int getUnreadSmsCount(Context context) { 
         String SMS_READ_COLUMN = "read"; 
         String UNREAD_CONDITION = SMS_READ_COLUMN + "=0"; 
         int count = 0; 
         Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query( 
               SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI, 
               new String[] { SMS_ID }, 
               UNREAD_CONDITION, null, null); 
         if (cursor != null) { 
            try { 
               count = cursor.getCount(); 
            } finally { 
               cursor.close(); 
            } 
         } 
         // We ignored the latest incoming message so add one to the 
total count 
         //   count += 1; 
         return count; 
   }
```

Comment: This might just work. However, it's not guaranteed to work on every device. Do consider this fact as well.